# Solving a system of the form $\{ux^n + vx^n = c_n\}$ for $n=0,1,2,3$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, systems-of-equations

Problem:

> Solve the system:
>   $$\begin{cases} u+v=2 \\
>  ux+vy=1 \\
>  ux^2+vy^2=-1 \\
>  ux^3+vy^3=-5 
> \end{cases}$$

My approach: If we sum relations we get $u(x^3+x^2+x+1) + v(y^3+y^2+y+1) = -3$. About giving $u=v$ and $x=y$ I get nothing. Any ideas?

Comment: This is linear in $u$ and $v.$ At least you can reduce this to a $2×2$ system. Didn't you even try this?

Comment: What are you supposed to solve for? All of the variables?

Answer (score 5):

From the first two equations, we draw $u,v$:

$$\begin{cases}u=\dfrac{2y-1}{y-x},\\v=\dfrac{1-2x}{y-x}.\end{cases}$$

Plugging in the last two,

$$\begin{cases}-2xy+x+y=-1,\\x^2+xy+y^2-2xy^2-2yx^2=-5.\end{cases}\\$$

and setting $s:=x+y,p:=xy$,
$$\begin{cases}-2p+s=-1,\\s^2-p-2ps=-5.\end{cases}$$

After elimination of $p$, we easily get $s=3,p=2$ and $x=1,y=2$ or conversely. Finally, $u=3,v=-1$ or conversely.

---

Note that the option $x=y$ must be rejected.

Comment: is it worth mentioning that if you assumed $x = y$ (i.e. assumed that the matrix didn't have full rank to solve for $(u, v)$ in the first part), you'd deduce $x = y =  \frac{1}{2}$ and then find an inconsistent system in $(u,v)$ using the last two equations?

Comment: @Rollen: if you like. This case is relatively easy to handle.

Comment: [+1] Fair play...

Answer (score 1):

From the initial equations we have: 
$$
ux^2 + vy^2 = (ux + vy)(x + y) - (u + v)xy \Rightarrow -1 = x + y - 2xy,
$$
and
$$
ux^3 + vy^3 = (ux^2 + vy^2)(x + y) - (ux + vy)xy \Rightarrow 5 = x + y + xy;
$$
if we set $a = x + y$ and $b = xy$, we have the system of equations:
$$
\begin{cases}
a - 2b = -1 \\
a + b = 5
\end{cases}
$$
with solution $(a,b) = (3, 2)$. Hence, $x$ and $y$ are solutions to the quadratic $x^2 - 3x + 2 = 0$, yielding two cases: $(x, y) = (1, 2)$ or $(x, y) = (2, 1)$. For the first case, the second equation of the system becomes $u + 2v = 1$, which with the first one leads to $(u, v) = (3, -1)$, hence a solution to the original system is $(u,v,x,y) = (3,-1,1,2)$; for the second case, by symmetry, we get $(u,v,x,y) = (-1,3,2,1)$.

Comment: [+1]  Fine derivation.

Answer (score 0):

We can eliminate $u$, $v$ and $x$ so that
$$
u=\frac{4y^2 - 4y + 1}{2y^2 - 2y - 1},\;
v=-\frac{3}{2y^2 - 2y - 1},\;
x=\frac{y + 1}{2y - 1}
$$
Then the first three equations hold, and the last one is
$$
3y^2-9y+6=0.
$$

Comment: See my questioning at the end of my "answer".

Comment: @DietrichBurde: there are exactly two solutions.

Comment: Yes, I am sorry. I forgot the last equation.

Answer (score 0):

**[Disclaimer : I don't pretend that I give here a solution ; it is only an insight about the situation allowing to predict (almost without calculation and almost certainly) the fact that there exists a finite number of solutions].**

In such cases with intricated non-linear equations, let us provide this insight with a geometrical viewpoint.

As the LHSs of the equations are homogeneous in $u,v$, let us set $u=2k, v=2k-2$.

Let us as well set $x_1:=x, x_2:=y$ in order that the 3 last equations can be given the following barycentric "shape" :

$$k\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}t_1\\t_1^2\\t_3^3\end{pmatrix}}_{P_1}+(1-k)\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}t_2\\t_2^2\\t_2^3\end{pmatrix}}_{P_2}=\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix} \ \ \ 1/2\\-1/2\\-5/2\end{pmatrix}}_{P}\tag{1}$$

$P_1,P_2$ belong to the same curve [which, besides, is a known curve, "archetype" of cubic Bézier curves in 3D]. Relationship (1)  means that $P_1, P_2,P$ are aligned.

One can say that for a fixed $P_1$, and a variable $P_2$ on the curve, the set of lines $P_1P_2$ defines a 2D surface (a sort of assymetrical conical surface with apex $P_1$ as shown on the figure for a certain position of $P_1$) that in general hasn't given point $P$ on it. With other words, it is hopefully for exceptional positions of $P_1$ that it happens to be the case.

[image]

*Fig. 1 : Representation of the solution where $P_1(1,1^2,1^3), P_2(2,2^2,2^3)$ are aligned with $M(1/2,-1/2,-5/2)$.*

I stop there this qualitative analysis (a methodology that can be applied to other similar cases) ; it has, so I think a "didactic interest" but  of course a deeper analysis is needed.

I have - since - discovered the neat results of @Yves Daoust and @Jose Ramirez.

Comment: The system is not homogeneous in $u,v$.

Comment: Stritly speaking, it is its LHS which is homogneous. I will correct it.

Comment: I have been downvoted  though I think I have brought something. I consider it as very  unfair.

Comment: I must admit that it took me a while to understand this analysis and I still wonder in what way it brings us closer to the solution. I also tried to find a useful geometric interpretation based on the "cubic" $(1,t,t^2,t^3)$ but quickly dropped.

Comment: @Yves Daoust Just added a graphical representation to show the **insight** (not more) on the issue brought by this geometrical standpoint.

Comment: Can you explain in concrete terms how this helps finding the solution(s) ?

Comment: @Yves Daoust Anticipate (almost without calculation) the fact that there is hopefuly at most a finite number of solutions, which is a qualitive result of some importance.

Comment: I expect a $4\times4$ system to have a finite number of solutions, except in degenerate cases.

Comment: Degenerate cases are numerous. You can perfectly have a hidden relationship that makes for instance the 4th equation a consequence of the 3 first. I stop there.

Comment: I guess that we can argument on the fact that the polynomials $1,x,x^2,x^3$ are linearly independent, but I don't see clearly how to formalize this.